# How to extract line numbers from an inbut box

Tags: vba, excel-2010

Excel VBA: My problem is simple (as am I!!). I need to use an "Input Box" to input a number (3 digits = xxx) and end up with a goto Linexxx i.e Line is text, xxx is (obviously) variable. Ive tried trying to string the xxx to a Text "Line" using & (ampersand) i.e. goto "Line"&Cont1 (Cont1 is a "variant"), but VBA gives "compile error: Expected Line Number or Label". As I am fairly new to VBA, could someone point me in the right direction, please. Thank you

Comment: see   http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?39352-Call-Sub-GoTo-Point

Comment: Thanks for the link, however not being very familiar with excel VBA (or any VBA), I'm having trouble applying it to my problem. Each of the suggestions seems to imply x number of sub routines to call x no of lines, 5 lines is fine, how do you cope with 30 or 40 lines?

Comment: Code in general is made of 2 phases: compile time (i.e. the moment when your computer interprets the code you wrote and understands what to do) and runtime (i.e. the moment when your computer runs the code. All the code must be known at compile time, while variables can/will be defined at runtime. In your case, you're trying to define the piece of your code `GoTo Line & Cont1` at runtime (i.e. after the user inputs the variable), but you cannot because all code should be known at compile time and that's why you're getting a compile error.

Comment: What you can do is to use a `Select Case` statement where to each `Case` corresponds your `GoTo`. For example: `Select Case Cont1` `Case "XXX":` `GoTo LineXXX` `Case "YYY":` `GoTo LineYYY` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Not knowing where you are in the world, suffice it to say that it's getting late here, and bed calls. I'll try again tomorrow. Regards